# What are the types of <K,V> in InputSampler<K,V>?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm a newbie in Hadoop world. I want to know what are the types of `<K,V>` in `InputSampler<K,V>` or `InputSampler.Sampler<K,V>`? This is equal to key and value coming out from `Mapper`? The examples on 
Internet don't use them. For example this [link](http://pipiper.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/sorting-using-hadoop-totalorderpartitioner/) just instantiate it without generics:

```
InputSampler.Sampler sampler = new InputSampler.RandomSampler(pcnt, numSamples, maxSplits);
```

Comment: Most probably the types you instantiate it with.

Comment: @Shail016 I know Java generics :D. I asked question because examples on Internet don't use them.

Comment: sorry your question didn't sound like that, pre edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [when looking at the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/0.23.1/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/partition/InputSampler.java#127), K denotes the type of the key, V denotes the value type. The real `Writable` type depends on what kind of input you want to sample, in that sense- yes it is similar to what you would use in a `Mapper`.

```
  RecordReader<K,V> reader = inf.createRecordReader(splits.get(i), samplingContext);
  reader.initialize(splits.get(i), samplingContext);
  while (reader.nextKeyValue()) {
    samples.add(ReflectionUtils.copy(job.getConfiguration(),
    reader.getCurrentKey(), null));
  }
```